# How to trim a javascript array

Tags: javascript

I want to trim an array after splitting my springs

```js
data = ',VALDESC::Value Date/PDESC::Description/REFNO::Txn Ref/REF.FT::Narration/POST::Booking Date/DR.AMT::Debit/CR.AMOUNT::Credit/BALANCE::Closing Balance,"","14 MAY 19 " "Cash Withdrawal    " "TT19134V74S7 " "                                   " "14 MAY 19" "4000" "" "-4000","","21 MAY 19 " "Bulk Payment (NAMBU" "FT19141911080" "                                   " "21 MAY 19" "" "71630.33" "90477.42","BEIGN STAFF AMY 2019 SAL","21 MAY 19 " "Bulk Payment (NAMBU" "FT19141912082" "                                   " "21 MAY 19" "2000" "" "88477.42","STAFF COOP MAY 2019","22 MAY 19 " "Cash Withdrawal    " "TT1914247YZ5 " "                                   " "22 MAY 19" "5000" "" "83477.42","","24 MAY 19 " "POS Purchase       " "FT19144536496" "                                   " "24 MAY 19" "3400" "" "80077.42","@ MEGA CHICKEN RESTAUR LA LANG STAN","" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "053588                             ","24 MAY 19 " "POS Purchase       " "FT19144019378" "                                   " "24 MAY 19" "1400" "" "78677.42","@ MEGA CHICKEN RESTAUR LA LANG STAN","" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "160419                             ","27 MAY 19 " "ATM Cash Withdrawal" "FT19147487249" "                                   " "27 MAY 19" "2000" "" "76677.42","@ 1 IKOYI ROAD OBALENDE LAGOS LANG ","" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "STAN 008029                        ","","","","","","","           76677.42" "" ""'

const lines = data.split('","');

for (let i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {

  var g = lines[i].trim();

}

console.log(g);
const headerline = lines[0];
const splitHeaderline = headerline.split('/');
```

Comment: when i do a split i discover that there are white spaces. now how do i trim this whites spaces

Comment: `data.split('","').map(s => s.trim())`?

Comment: Use the functional methods of Array like: `map` and `filter`.

Comment: @crashmstr there are spaces in the middle of the split strings, that's what they're referring to. EDIT: actually, the more I read the question, the less I understand what they mean...

Comment: You're not doing anything with the `g` variable in that loop. You probably wanted to do `lines[i] = lines[i].trim();`

Comment: I bet you don't need the first part of the string, so just select with `\".*?\"` regex, then trim elements of result array

Comment: Please make your question clearer by including expected input and expected output.  It is not clear how you want to filter at the moment.

Comment: Do you have any control over that serialized data format?  It looks quite difficult to work with as it.  Can you alter it, or is that out of your control?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to "remove" blank element on the array and not trim them.

```js
data = ',VALDESC::Value Date/PDESC::Description/REFNO::Txn Ref/REF.FT::Narration/POST::Booking Date/DR.AMT::Debit/CR.AMOUNT::Credit/BALANCE::Closing Balance,"","14 MAY 19 " "Cash Withdrawal    " "TT19134V74S7 " "                                   " "14 MAY 19" "4000" "" "-4000","","21 MAY 19 " "Bulk Payment (NAMBU" "FT19141911080" "                                   " "21 MAY 19" "" "71630.33" "90477.42","BEIGN STAFF AMY 2019 SAL","21 MAY 19 " "Bulk Payment (NAMBU" "FT19141912082" "                                   " "21 MAY 19" "2000" "" "88477.42","STAFF COOP MAY 2019","22 MAY 19 " "Cash Withdrawal    " "TT1914247YZ5 " "                                   " "22 MAY 19" "5000" "" "83477.42","","24 MAY 19 " "POS Purchase       " "FT19144536496" "                                   " "24 MAY 19" "3400" "" "80077.42","@ MEGA CHICKEN RESTAUR LA LANG STAN","" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "053588                             ","24 MAY 19 " "POS Purchase       " "FT19144019378" "                                   " "24 MAY 19" "1400" "" "78677.42","@ MEGA CHICKEN RESTAUR LA LANG STAN","" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "160419                             ","27 MAY 19 " "ATM Cash Withdrawal" "FT19147487249" "                                   " "27 MAY 19" "2000" "" "76677.42","@ 1 IKOYI ROAD OBALENDE LAGOS LANG ","" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "STAN 008029                        ","","","","","","","           76677.42" "" ""'

const lines = data.split('","')
    .filter(el => !!el) // Remove blank elements
    .map(el => el.trim())  // Remove white space before and after
console.log(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I wrote some code to parse that format according to my best guess about the structure, it's not pretty, and that is mostly due to the craziness of that format.  If you have any control over it, I would suggest that you export something more reasonable.  But I made a number of assumptions and ended up with this code:

```js
const process = (data) => {
  const headerEnd = ',"",'
  const end = data .indexOf (headerEnd)
  const rawHeader = data .slice (1, end)
  const headers = rawHeader
    .split ('/')
    .map (s => s.split('::'))
    .map (([name, desc]) => ({name, desc}))
    .concat ({name: '', desc: 'Unknown'})
  const len = headers .length;
  
  const fields = data.slice(end + headerEnd.length)
    .split(/\t|,/).map(s => s.slice(1, -1).trim())

  const body = Array (Math .ceil (fields .length / len))
    .fill ()
    .map ((_, i) => fields. slice (i * len, i * len + len))
    .map (
      fields => headers .reduce (
        (a, {name, desc}, i) => ({...a, [desc]: fields[i]}),
        {}
      )
    )
 
  return {headers, body}
}

const data = ',VALDESC::Value Date/PDESC::Description/REFNO::Txn Ref/REF.FT::Narration/POST::Booking Date/DR.AMT::Debit/CR.AMOUNT::Credit/BALANCE::Closing Balance,"","14 MAY 19 " "Cash Withdrawal    " "TT19134V74S7 " "                                   " "14 MAY 19" "4000" "" "-4000","","21 MAY 19 " "Bulk Payment (NAMBU" "FT19141911080" "                                   " "21 MAY 19" "" "71630.33" "90477.42","BEIGN STAFF AMY 2019 SAL","21 MAY 19 " "Bulk Payment (NAMBU" "FT19141912082" "                                   " "21 MAY 19" "2000" "" "88477.42","STAFF COOP MAY 2019","22 MAY 19 " "Cash Withdrawal    " "TT1914247YZ5 " "                                   " "22 MAY 19" "5000" "" "83477.42","","24 MAY 19 " "POS Purchase       " "FT19144536496" "                                   " "24 MAY 19" "3400" "" "80077.42","@ MEGA CHICKEN RESTAUR LA LANG STAN","" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "053588                             ","24 MAY 19 " "POS Purchase       " "FT19144019378" "                                   " "24 MAY 19" "1400" "" "78677.42","@ MEGA CHICKEN RESTAUR LA LANG STAN","" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "160419                             ","27 MAY 19 " "ATM Cash Withdrawal" "FT19147487249" "                                   " "27 MAY 19" "2000" "" "76677.42","@ 1 IKOYI ROAD OBALENDE LAGOS LANG ","" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "STAN 008029                        ","","","","","","","           76677.42" "" ""'

console .log (
  process (data)
)
```

It generates output like this:

```js
{
  headers: [
    {
      name: 'VALDESC',
      desc: 'Value Date'
    },
    {
      name: 'PDESC',
      desc: 'Description'
    },
  // ...
  ],
  body: [
    {
      'Value Date': '14 MAY 19',
      Description: 'Cash Withdrawal',
      'Txn Ref': 'TT19134V74S7',
      Narration: '',
      'Booking Date': '14 MAY 19',
      Debit: '4000',
      Credit: '',
      'Closing Balance': '-4000",
      Unknown: ''
    },
    {
      'Value Date': '21 MAY 19',
      Description: 'Bulk Payment (NAMBU',
      'Txn Ref': 'FT19141911080',
      Narration: '',
      'Booking Date': '21 MAY 19',
      Debit: '',
      Credit: '71630.33',
      'Closing Balance': '90477.42',
      'Unknown': 'BEIGN STAFF AMY 2019 SAL'
    },
    // ...
  ]
}
```

You could change the keys here from the longer descriptive phrase to the shorthand, simply by replacing

```js
        (a, {name, desc}, i) => ({...a, [desc]: fields[i]}),
```

with

```js
        (a, {name, desc}, i) => ({...a, [name]: fields[i]}),
```

And obviously if you have no need of the headers, you can return simply `body`.

But again, I would not use code like this if I had any hope of altering the input format.

Comment: How do i append unknown to description. the unknown values is a continuation of description. thanks